# Abbreviated author names with initials at the end in the reference list

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, miktex, texworks

I use TexMaker with TeXworks to write a paper. The comments I use are given below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort & compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section_1}
\section{Section_2}
\section{Section_3}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt,firstinit=true}
\bibliography{Bibfile}

\end{document}
```

I generated Bibfile using Mendeley. In the LaTeX generated file, following issues are there:

1. Author names are abbreviated and some are not; I need all authors name in all the references abrreviated.
2. In some references, issue numbers also present. I want to remove it.
3. In some references, month is also displayed before the year (may 2015). But I need only the year.

Simply, the format I want is the following:

"*Charles, A. B. and Daniel, B. C., Title of the Paper, Journal Name, Vol_No.: Page_Numbers, Year*."

Thanks in advance for any help/hint to solve these issues.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The instruction `\bibliographystyle{unsrt,firstinit=true}` doesn't look right: the macro `\bibliographystyle` takes only one argument, the name of a bibliography style file.

Comment: Your formatting requirements may be sufficiently unique so as to make it unlike that any existing style satisfies all of them. You may want to look into running the `makebst` utility -- part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package -- to create a bespoke bibliography style from scratch.

Comment: Incidentally, should one of the requirements be that the formatted entries shouldn't be sorted alphabetically, but instead should be listed in the order they are cited in the body of the document?

Comment: @Mico The references should be listed in the order they are cited in the body of the document.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. In this case, I would definitely like to encourage you to learn how to run the `makebst` utility, if you want to stick with BibTeX.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I don't want to stick with BibTeX. Any other suggestion?

Comment: There's the `biblatex` package to consider. Be aware, though, that the switching costs associated from `natbib`/BibTeX to `biblatex` may be at least as high as learning how to run the `makebst` utility to create a bespoke bibliography style file that implements all of your formatting requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mico for your suggession. I will start to learn makebst.

Comment: I've voted to close your posting, not because I think it's not a good question [!], but because I think it's a duplicate of sorts to an earlier posting that asks a fairly similar question, and to which the accepted answer was to look into using the `makebst` utility. Happy BibTeXing!